# Inhibited population growth versus disease growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The rate population growth within a contained system is proportional to the current population y and the distance between y and the limit capacity L.  The ODE is given by :

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = ky ( 1 - $\frac{y}{L}$)

The rate of disease growth within a population L is proportional to those already infected y and those not yet infected (L-y).  This ODE is given by:

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = ky (L - y)

What is the intuitive difference between the 2 equations?

The rate of growth of each both tend to zero as the population tends to the respective limit, but how does the approach behaviour differ between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you rewrite the first equation as
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {ky}  {L} (L-y)$$

you can see that the difference with the second equation reduces to a constant in the RHS.

Comment: That clears up a lot, thank you!  On another note, upon solving the ODEs I found that after a partial fractions expansion, one of my fractions is ∫dy/L-y.  Here, if I integrate as is, the end solution in y is quadratic. If I factor out -1, then integrate the solution in y looks very different due to logarithmic arithmetic.  Does it matter which method I choose? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only factor out $-1$, there should be no particular differences between the two final results.

Comment: Thank you. The calculus makes sense to me, but the inherent reasoning behind it doesn't. Why does the latter approach the limit faster than the former?

Comment: Seeing as both equations describe growth within a closed system

Comment: The reasoning is as follows: in the first case, the rate of change is proportional to the current population $y $ with a given property (being alive or being infected) and the distance between $y $ and the limit capacity $L$, through a constant that does not depend on the capacity. In the second case, the rate of change is again proportional to $y $ and the distance between $y$ and $L$, but through a constant that DOES depend on the capacity.